# Accessing parameters within CLI class

Tags: php, symfony

How can I get parameters from a yml file in class below so that I can print it with CLI?

**Error**:

```
mbp:symfony em$ app/console phing:report
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Site\CommonBundle\Command\GreetCommand::getParameter() in symfony/src/Site/CommonBundle/Command/GreetCommand.php on line 25
```

**symfony/src/Site/CommonBundle/Command/GreetCommand.php**

```
namespace Site\CommonBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class GreetCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('phing:report');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $user = $this->getParameter('dummy_user');
        $output->writeln($user['admin']['username']);
    }
}
```

**symfony/app/config/globals_dev.yml**

```
#Site globals

parameters:
    dummy_user:
        admin:
            username: admin
        superadmin:
            username: superadmin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to simply get a parameter from the container, you can access it like this from the CLI:

```
$this->getContainer()->getParameter('dummy_user');
```

Comment: As simple as that! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 4.3 or above you can inject all the application parameters at once with the ContainerBagInterface and then access to your parameter:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ContainerBagInterface;

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct(ContainerBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $yourParam = $this->params->get('hereYourParam');
    }
}
```

See: https://symfony.com/doc/master/configuration.html#accessing-configuration-parameters

This approach is valid for inject all parameters in a services but it works also in a Console command.